# Cannot resolved class Reasoner in Pellet/OwlApi

Tags: java, owl, pellet

I'm start to use Pellet to create a reasoner with my OWLApi application.
As in the examples, I start with this code:

```
Reasoner reasoner = new Reasoner( manager );
```

but Eclipse give me this error on "new Reasoner":

```
The type org.semanticweb.owl.model.OWLOntologyManager cannot be resolved. 
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

how can I solve this problem? I search on google, but the only response is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classpath problem. eclipse can't find `org.semanticweb.owl.model.OWLOntologyManager` on it's classpath. You're not importing this class directly but some other library does.

Try to identify the library that contains `org.semanticweb.owl.model.OWLOntologyManager` and add it to the classpath.